# How to execute local script (which executes another local script) in remote machine

Tags: bash, shell-script, ssh

I've written some script which looks like the following

`main.sh`

```bash
ls
./os.sh
```

`os.sh`

```bash
cat /etc/os-release
```

executing like

```bash
ssh user@serverA "bash -s" < ./main.sh "hi" "bye"
```

But this only works with the commands in `main.sh`, it fails to execute commands in `os.sh`
It tries to find `os.sh` in the remote machine. But how can this type of script can be run?

Comment: By first making sure that `os.sh` is available on the other machine? I mean, your script has a dependency (`os.sh`), so it seems obvious that all dependencies need to be installed before the script will run successfully.

Comment: Even if you where to execute the script that is on your system and not on serverA (f.e. by ssh-ing back), which `/etc/os-release` would you expect to get? It will be the one on your client.

Comment: @Kusalananda I understand that the script is dependent on `os.sh` but my intention was not to write a huge single file script (so I wanted to split up those scripts) and be able to execute that in the remote machine, but I don't want to put those (any of my script) in the remote machine. How can I execute this type of script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux doesn't have a built-in way of sharing a script file like `os.sh` between the two computers.

So to accomplish your goal of invoking the `os.sh` script on a remote computer, you have to put the script on the computer.  There are ways to do this temporarily and ways to do it "permanently".  A brief survey of options:

- If you have a filesystem that's shared between your local computer and the remote computers you're interested in, copy `os.sh` to the filesystem and invoke it from there.
- Create a package containing `os.sh`, add it to a local package repository and use the package management commands to install the package on all the computers where you may want to invoke it.
- Use a configuration management system like Puppet, Chef, Saltstack, etc. to install the `os.sh` file onto the computers you're interested in.  The script can be installed in package form (like the previous option), or by itself.
- Copy the `os.sh` script to the remote computer using `scp` and delete it after it's finished running.
- Use Ansible to automate copying the `os.sh` script to the remote computer, invoking it, and deleting it afterward.

The first three options are "permanent" ones, meaning the script is available on the remote server all the time, not just during your ssh session.  The last two are "temporary", putting the script on the server only long enough to invoke it.

The permanent techniques have a lot of additional work to create the infrastructure resources that the techniques depend on.  However, if you're working at a company with a lot of servers, one or the other of these resources may already be in place.

The temporary techniques are more self-reliant, not needing extra work to create the infrastructure.  A software suite named `Ansible` can automate the parts where you copy the script file to the remote host, invoke it, and delete it afterward.  Ansible defaults to operating over ssh, and it can even automatically sudo to root for you on the remote computer, if needed.

If you're only going to do this on one server and perhaps once a month, then performing your own scp/delete is probably what you'll want.  If you have do do this kind of thing often or do it on a lot of remote computers, then I recommend installing Ansible on your local computer and learn the fairly simple commands it has to copy/invoke/delete scripts on remote servers.

Comment: Thank you very much for providing many options with this much detail which really expanded my knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

You could transfer the whole directory with the scripts and all required dependencies into a temporary directory.

Assuming the login shell of `user` on `host` is POSIX-like and there are `mktemp`, `tar` and `gunzip` commands there, that could be:

```
tar cf - . | gzip -1 | ssh user@host '
  set -o errexit
  tmpdir=$(mktemp -d)
  trap '\''rm -rf -- "$tmpdir"'\'' EXIT TERM HUP ALRM
  cd -P -- "$tmpdir"
  gunzip | tar xf -
  ./main.sh'
```

Comment: You've broad up things that I didn't know, like `mktemp`. I'm fairly new to Linux. I was in great trouble in choosing the answer to accept, Both solved my issue.
Thank you very much